# In python opencv, is there a way to match keypoints for a colour image?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, sift

Keypoint matching in OpenCV uses a greyscale image internally.

Is there any way at all - implicitly or explicitly - to exploit the colour information in an image for matching?

Is e.g. CSIFT (see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4246242_CSIFT_A_SIFT_descriptor_with_color_invariant_characteristics) implemented in python (in opencv or anywhere else)?

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51585/scale-and-rotation-invariant-color-based-feature-descriptors has some ideas on algorithms, but mentions no implementation.

[Color and feature classification opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188334/color-and-feature-classification-opencv) pertains but doesn't give a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

The keypoint matching methods uses to avoiding color information, because of that the color can be changed by illumination. So, color based methods generally is not preferred. If you want to use color information, you should fix environment with the illumination.
But, maybe [this](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d17/group__ximgproc__filters.html#ga370f180e4a52231ba218adbb4a65a9ca) can work for your problem.